# How to pass value returned from 1st method to the 2nd one

Tags: function, class, kotlin, methods

let's say I declare a class, which take an Int number as parameter, in class body there are 2 method.

- The 1st method is to handle the input number (if it's out of range 0..20, then will be adjusted to be within the range by using x%20.
- The 2nd method is doing more work but need the input which is result from method 1.

So how can I pass the method 1's result to method 2? Below is my code

```
class number (var input:Int) {
    private fun inputHandler():Int {
        return input % 20
    }

    fun print() {
        println(output)  //output here is returned value from method inputHandler
    }     
}

fun main() {
    val num1 = number(-3)
    val num2 = number(26)
    val num3 = number(30)
    num1.print()
    num2.print()
    num3.print()
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `inputHandler` from `print`? Or let the constructor adjust the value and assign it to a member field.

Comment: @Michael I dont know that i actually can do that =)) i tried to assign an extra variable for the returned value but cannot call it in print() method. And how to use the constructor? I want to try several ways

Answer (score 0):

```
class number (var input:Int){
private fun inputHandler():Int { 
    if(input>20){return input%20}else{return input}
     }
fun print() { println(inputHandler()) }  }     //output here is returned value from method inputHandler

fun main() {
val num1 = number(-3); val num2 = number(26); val num3 = number(30)
num1.print()
num2.print()
num3.print()
}
```

please check if the above code gives you the desired result..